# Could i have written this any simpler?

Tags: javascript

This is a test on freecodecamp.com and i just wanna know if i could have written this simpler or if this is okay?

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if(prop !== "tracks" && value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }

  else if(prop == "tracks" && collection[id].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false){
    collection[id][prop] = [];
    collection[id][prop].push(value);
  }

  else if(prop == "tracks" && value !== ""){
    collection[id][prop].push(value);
  }
  else if(value === ""){
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }

  return collection;
}

updateRecords(2468, "tracks", "Free");
```

Comment: Your last `else if` condition could be removed in favor of just `else`

Comment: Probably a better forum for this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You would want to test it, but it seems to me that `collection[id].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false` could be better expressed as `!collection[id][prop]`

Comment: what happens to `track` with an empty `value`? schould the whole array be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Try by check `props === 'tracks' only once`

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if(prop !== "tracks" && value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }
  else if(prop === 'tracks'){
     if(collection[id].hasOwnProperty(prop) === false){
       collection[id][prop] = [];
       collection[id][prop].push(value);
     }
     else if(value !== "" ){
       collection[id][prop].push(value);
     }
  }
  else if(value === ""){
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }
  return collection;
}
```

Comment: You have some errors in your tracks `else if` block. Non empty `value` will be appended twice. And you could remove the first `collection[id][prop].push(value);` call all together.